# What are stripe cocoapods. How do i install them?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, stripe-payments

I am trying set up Stripe in my IOS app, but i have no clue what these instructions mean?
Is cocoapods an application i install?

> Step 1: Install Stripe Cocapod(s)
>
> CocoaPods is a common library dependency management tool for iOS
>    development. To use the Stripe CocoaPods, simply add the following to
>    your Podfile and run pod install:
>
> pod 'Stripe'
>   pod 'PaymentKit'
>
> Note: be sure to use the .xcworkspace to
>    open your project in Xcode instead of the .xcproject.

Here is the guide i am using to set up Stripe... [Guide](http://sapan.svbtle.com/stripe-ios-integration-in-swift)

Comment: You have to install first cocoapods on your Mac. Then use cocoapods command to install Stripe to your project. Read "Install" and "Get started" in their website: https://cocoapods.org/

Comment: Easiest tutorial is [Ray Wenderlich's Introduction to cocoapods](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2)

Comment: you can find it at this link: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&ui=payment-sheet#setup-client-side (choose cocoa pods from tabs)

Answer (score 2):

CocoaPods is a dependency manager.

1. Install CocoaPods. `sudo gem install cocoapods`. You may need to `pod setup` afterwards.
2. **Go into your project directory** and `pod init`. This will generate a Podfile.
3. Go ahead and **edit the Podfile with your favourite editor** (vim, emacs, flame wars...). **Enter `pod 'Stripe'` in one line under your target, and also enter `pod 'PaymentKit'` in a second line.** This will install these two frameworks and their dependencies.
4. Run `pod install` for CocoaPods to *magically* install the required dependencies.
5. Open your `$project.xcworkspace`. The workspace includes your project as well as your pods target which generates the necessary frameworks.

You're done! Enjoy Stripe and PaymentKit!

Comment: The instructions are not clear. Where do i run the 'sudo gem install cocoapods' code? where is my project directory? Please be more descriptive.

Comment: When i run 'sudo gen install cocoapods' in terminal, i get this message "nachshonfertel is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

Answer (score 0):

**cocoa pod installation step :**

*Open Your Terminal :*

```
sudo gem update --system

sudo gem install cocoapods

pod setup
```

*Then Go To Your Project Directory*

```
pod init

open -a Xcode Podfile
```

*[Edit POD file with pod ‘libname’ ]*

```
pod install
```